# Python Contour index

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm getting my feet wet with python in the field Calculator. I'm working with 
contour data and I'm  looking to see if someone can help me.

I basically need to do [this](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000004672), but with python.

Comment: Links are fine to use as background to a question but should not form part of it.  Potential answerers should not be expected to follow links to synthesize what it is that you want to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def setindex(height):
 dIndexInterval = 50
 dCont = height
 i = dCont / dIndexInterval
 if  ( dCont / dIndexInterval) - i == 0:
  return 1
 else:
  return 0
```

And then `setindex( !ELEV! )` in the bottom window where ELEV is the name of your elevation field.

**Edit**
The code given in the link looks buggy, as far as I can tell it will always return 1. The code below should work correctly if modulo is used instead to find the index contours.

```
def setindex(height):
 dIndexInterval = 50
 dCont = height
 if  dCont % dIndexInterval == 0:
  return 1
 else:
  return 0
```

Comment: Could something be wrong with the calculation.  As it stands all the values are going to be 1. or am I Missing Something?

Comment: I think something is wrong with the logic in the link you posted, from what i can see the returned value will always be 1. To be honest if I was  looking for index contours I would use the modulo operation. something like "if dCont % dIndexInterval == 0"

Comment: That Works perfect.